# Batch file to find all files in a directory containing an HTML string then output list to a text file

Tags: search, batch-file

I've made several attempts at this but get nothing but "can't open..." errors, so I'm asking here:

I want to find all instances of the string "SOME TEXT" within a directory full of HTML files. Then the search results should be output to a file in that same directory (D:\myfiles)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample batch file that'll do the trick.

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd D:\myfiles

rem case-insensitive search for the string "SOME TEXT" in all html files
rem in the current directory, piping the output to the results.txt file
rem in teh same directory
findstr /ip /c:"SOME TEXT" *.html > results.txt

popd
endlocal
```

**Update**: Some caveats to using findstr command.

If your string contains angle brackets, you have to escape them using the CMD escape character - ^. So, if you want to search for `<TITLE>`, you have to specify it as `/c:"^<TITLE^>"`.

If you want only file names, change /ip to /im. Also, you can add /s to search subfolders. In general, you can play with the different findstr options as listed in findstr /?.

Findstr will find the text only in UTF-8 encoded files. If the HTML files are UTF-16 encoded (ie, each character takes two bytes), findstr will not find the text.

I would also suggest running the command without the piping to the results.txt first to get the right findstr options and make sure it outputs what you need.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer - 
Using the code shown below created a results file. However it did not seem to be outputting filenames, but the actual code that contained the string. 

@echo off
setlocal

pushd d:\Sites
findstr /ip /c:"THE" *.htm > results.txt

popd
endlocal

But, it only worked once! When "THE" was changed to the real string:  "<TITLE>OUR COURSES:</TITLE>"
it stopped working. No more results file, no error, nothing. 

Thinking the brackets might be the problem, I changed it to "OUR COURSES:" but no luck. Even when changed back to "THE" it doesn't work!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%f in (*.html) do findstr /i /m /p /c:"SOME TEXT" "%%f" >> results.txt
```